# Howto callback a non-modal/modeless dialog in Blender?

Tags: python

I'm writing a very simple script, that get input string from popup dialog and print on console.
But the invoke_props_dialog operator cannot satisfy my requirement. It is a modal operator, I find no way to get its return into the main thread/main(). My code is below,

```
import bpy

input_str = None

def main():
    global input_str
    bpy.ops.message.input('INVOKE_SCREEN')
    
    return print(input_str)
    

class InputDialog(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "message.input"
    bl_description = 'Dialog for input string.'
    bl_label = ""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
 
    prompt : bpy.props.StringProperty()

 
    def execute(self, context):
        global input_str
        input_str = self.prompt
        return {'FINISHED'}

 
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

 
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(self, 'prompt', text='')


classes = (
    InputDialog,
    )


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        unregister()
    except:
        pass

    register()
    main()
```

What should I do to use invoke_props_dialog in non-modal way, or find another non-modal operator for my intent? Any advices are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Although you can use ```global``` in native python scripts, I doubt it works well in Blender Environment (with calls being translated to C). If you want just to print the input of the string, do it in the ```execute``` call, or place your ```prompt``` property in some other datablock and write/read directly from there.